# Symfony/doctrine - DQL order by parameter not defined

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

can anyone tell me why this code does not work :

```
$sort = 'u.username'; //test

$dql = 'SELECT u, p FROM GPAuthBundle:User u
    JOIN u.profile p
    WHERE ( u.username LIKE :username )
    AND ( u.username LIKE :search OR p.name LIKE :search )
    ORDER BY :sort ASC';

$parameters = array(
    'username' => '%'.$request->query->get('username').'%',
    'search' => '%'.$request->query->get('search').'%',
    'sort' => $sort
);

$query = $manager->createQuery($dql)->setParameters($parameters);
```

The error :

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 170 near ':sort ASC': Error: ':sort' is not defined.

Comment: Doctrine expects a column name, not a named parameter. You can't do that this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use in ORDER because `setParameters()` puts quotes : `ORDER BY "myvalue" ASC` and you want `ORDER BY myvalue ASC`

Use PHP var, example :

```
ORDER BY ' . $sort . ' ASC
```